# getting span tag value in for loop not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Having this code:

html:

```
<div id="div-1">item1</div>
<div id="div-2">item2</div>
<div id="div-3">item3</div>
```

js:

```
  for (var j=0; j < 2; j++){
    var item = $('#div-'+j).text();
    console.log(item);
    }
```

I need to be able to conditionate items based on their "text", but for some reason the loop's output is always empty.

Any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: Your divs have the same ids

Comment: `$('#div-'+j)`? Use `#` for id.

Comment: `$("#div-1").eq(j)`  (pre-edit where they all had the same id, after edit, could be `$("div").eq(j)` but most likely you'd want as @Eddie stated - ie you just missed "#")

Comment: sorry tap issue... Actually they have different ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing the `#` sign in the `$('div-'+j)`, besides that, all your `div` have the same id.

```js
for (var j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
  var item = $('#div-' + j).text();
  console.log(item);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div-1">item1</div>
<div id="div-2">item2</div>
<div id="div-3">item3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that the Ids have been fixed by your edit, you should just need to change the numbers of the loop to match

```
 for (var j=0; j < 2; j++){
var item = $('#div-'+j).text();
console.log(item);
}
```

should become

```
 for (var j=1; j < 4; j++){
var item = $('#div-'+j).text();
console.log(item);
}
```

to match your div ids of 1, 2 & 3